# Comment truncation in Teams

Tags: bug, comments, stack-overflow-for-teams

In the following situation ...

1. I post an answer
2. Someone posts a comment
3. I reply with another comment

... the software automatically adds `@username` at the start of my comment.

If my comment was already maximum-permitted-length, then it's truncated when I post it -- truncated because of the extra `@username` which the software auto-adds at the beginning.

The behaviour -- the software automatically adding an "at username" -- is something I've only seen on a Team site, not on a regular SO/SE site.

Comment: buffer overflow!

Comment: work-around: edit the comment, delete the auto-added name, re-add the truncated text, and save